# How can I know that PowerShell function parameter is omitted

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

Consider such function:

```
function Test($foo, $bar)
{
  ...
}
```

We can call it:

```
Test -foo $null
Test
```

How can I know when the -foo was omitted, and when it was $null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Powershell V2 or later, you can use the $PSBoundParameters variable which is a dictionary that lists all bound parameters at current scope.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/04/06/checking-for-bound-parameters.aspx)  blog post that discusses it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is possible to trap exceptions thrown from param statement (and since param has to be the first, I can't see this would work):

```
function {
  trap { "Something failed" }
  param($foo = $(throw "Foo not specified"))
  ...
```

Then I can't see a way (you get the same thing with [switch] parameters: default or explicitly `-mySwitch:$false`).

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on Richard's idea:

```
$missed = "{716C1AD7-0DA6-45e6-854E-4B466508EB96}"

function Test($foo = $missed, $bar)
{
    if($foo -eq $missed) {
        Write-Host 'Missed'
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Foo: $foo"
    }
}

Test -foo $null
Test
```